# Return sql record that contains the text from a php string

Tags: php, mysql

So somebody answered my question about grabbing records from a sql database if it contains any text from a string. It works fine, how ever my string contains commas, as does every record in my sql db.

Is there a way of skipping the commas in the database and just checking for the words before / after the comma?

For example :

```
$tags = "rock,pop,indie,alternitive rock, drum and bass";
$tags = explode(' ', $tags);
$tags = implode("%' OR `tags` LIKE '%", $tags);
$thetags = explode(' ', $thetags);
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Stations` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$tags%'" );
```

I only want it to check the records and return the results of the text within the commas. As if i do a search of the record now it returns every result as they all include a comma / space.

Hope this makes sense.
Jamie

Comment: Related: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can achieve it by making a few small changes:

```
<?php
$tags = "rock,pop,indie,alternitive rock,drum and bass";
$tags = addslashes($tags);
$tags_array = explode(',', $tags);
$tags_search = implode("%' OR `tags` LIKE '%", $tags_array);
$tags_query = "SELECT * FROM `Stations` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%".$tags_search."%'";
?>
```

1. Note that the `explode(',',$tags)` is separating based on commas, not spaces.
2. I removed the space in `rock, drum`.
3. I renamed your variables, as this may make it easier for you to keep an overview.
4. I also added an `addslashes` for improving your security a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If the stations in the DB only have one genre tag per station, you can use the MYSQL IN clause like below. I just used a str_replace() to add single quotes around your tag list to prepare it for the IN clause.

```
$tags = "rock,pop,indie,alternitive rock, drum and bass"; // from your post

$list = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $tags) . "'";  // add single quotes to tags

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Stations` WHERE `tags` IN (".$list.")";  // build query

$result1 = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Hi,

THanks for your help. I'm having a very weird issue though, it seems to work but for some tags it returns 0 results. Is this right?

$tags ="electronic,house,dance,electronica,techno,";
$list = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $tags) . "'";  
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Stations` WHERE `tags` IN (".$list.")" );


$num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);
echo $num_rows1;

Bare in my it should be returning 18 records.

Jamie

Comment: Without seeing the data, its hard to tell what's happening. Does every record have one tag?  Maybe try removing the comma at the end of your tag list. Is anything online we can see?